# Displaying a list of a customer's contacts in my details view

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, automapper, ef-database-first

**My overall goal is to be able to display all Customer Information in my CustomerController->Details View and have no idea how to pass all of this data:**
Customer info - (fields directly in Customer table)
Customer contacts
Customer locations
Customer documents

I am able to display the customer info just fine because I am doing something like this and passing it to my view:

```
public ActionResult Details(int? id)
{
    Model.Customer customer = _custService.GetCustByID(id);
    return View(customer);
}
```

I have absolutely no idea how to go from just this which gives me access to direct Customer properties in my view to displaying all of these other lists of related customer items that come from separate tables.

**Here are a few details on my project setup:**
I am using EF6DbFirst and I also create a Dto for each one of my entities and use AutoMapper to map everything. My Customer.cs model has all of the customer's direct properties and also a couple that look like this for the things that are one-to-many relationships:

```
public List<CustomerContact> Contacts { get; set; }
```

Now in my AutoMapper config I did the following since my table is named CustomerContacts in EF:

```
    CreateMap<Customer, Model.Customer>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Contacts, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CustomerContact));

    CreateMap<Customer_GetAll_Result, Model.Customer>();
```

I am not sure if this is the proper way to do this with AutoMapper or if there is anything else I have to tell it when accessing other tables. I am thinking the only reason I have to map this property is because I want to change the name to just c.Contacts rather than c.CustomerContacts.

**Side question:**
As you can see I am also trying to map values that come from my GetAll stored procedure which my custService.GetAll() uses in my controller to bind a grid of customers. I don't think this matters in this case but I am assuming if I ever need to loop through that list that comes from the proc and get the contacts for each customer they will not be available since my stored proc only returns direct customer properties which is why I can't do the mapping for that one. Is there any workaround for this?